# Ruby - Why this callback function doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I have this statement on my model:

```
class Question

    validates :closed, :inclusion => { :in => [false, true] }

    before_validation :ensure_default_data


    def ensure_default_data

        self.closed = false if self.closed.nil?

    end
end
```

When I call:

```
Question.create
```

It outputs me:

```
#<Question id:nil, closed: false>
```

If I modify the function to this:

```
def ensure_default_data
    self.closed = 0 if self.closed.nil?
end
```

It works!

Someone has any idea about it and why the first function doesn't work?

I'm using PostgreSQL and my field is boolean.

Comment: What database are you using? What is the column definition for that closed column in your model?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL! This is the migration: `add_column :questions, :closed, :boolean`

Comment: Can you clarify for me what you think is wrong? You appear to be trying to set the value of 'closed' to false if it is nil, which is what you first output shows??

Comment: please edit/update your question with all the additional data you privide (like the database). It's better if this info is in the question, and not in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul it instantiate but not create the object. @Sunny edited, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your callback is preventing the model from being saved. From http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks:

> If the returning value of a
>   before_validation callback can be
>   evaluated to false, the process will
>   be aborted and Base#save will return
>   false. If Base#save! is called it will
>   raise a ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
>   exception. Nothing will be appended to
>   the errors object.

When `self.closed` is not `nil` your callback returns the value of `self.closed.nil?` (ie `false`), thus stopping the save from happening. To prevent this, make sure you return true:

```
def ensure_default_data
  self.closed = false if self.closed.nil?
  true
end
```